# Why is samba denying me access to my drive installed newly on CentOS from windows?

Tags: linux, centos, samba

I mounted a new drive on `/New_drive` my CentOS 5.7 box running Samba (3.0.33-3.29) and configured in fstab as follows:

```
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
**/dev/VolGroup02/LogVol00 /New_drive     ext3    defaults        1 1**
```

I have two folders already shared and accessed via samba.

I have user smbuser having full access to these folder  from windows machines.
The smb.conf file has following configuration:

```
#======================= Global Settings =====================================

[global]

        workgroup = lab
        server string = Samba-server1
        coding system= euc
        client code page=932
        encrypt passwords=yes
        log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
        max log size = 50
        security = user
        passdb backend = tdbsam
#============================ Share Definitions ==============================
# Samba Files
        [share-lab]
        comment = Samba-files
        create mode=0777
        directory mode=0777
        path =/home/sambafiles
        writable = yes
        valid users = smbuser

#Samba backup  Files
        [Samba-Backup]
        comment = Backup
        create mode=0777
        directory mode=0777
        path =/home/sambabackup
        writable = yes
        valid users = smbuser
```

So, set the owner and of `/New_drive` as smbuser and give public acess to the folder.
and added New lines to the smb.conf

```
#New Drive
        [New-drive]
        comment = New-drive
        create mode=0777
        directory mode=0777
        path =/New_drive/sambafiles
        writable = yes
        valid users = smbuser
```

But, the New-drive is seen from the windows machine and is not acessible.
The log file recorded the error as

```
smbd/service.c:make_connection_snum(1013)
  '/New_drive/sambafiles' does not exist or permission denied when connecting to [Ohmi-New] Error was Permission denied
```

Can anyone suggest me the way to solve this problem?

Comment: What are the permissions of /New_drive in the filesystem and does /New_drive/sambafiles exist?

Comment: James is correct in asking for the perms, what are the results of running ls -ld /New_drive/ /New_drive/sambafiles/. But on an off chance, is selinux running? What is the result of getenforce?

Comment: @JamesO'Gorman thanx.. drwxrwxrwx 4 smbuser users 4.0K Jul 5 08:41 New_drive is the permission for the drive .. Of course i created '/New_drive/sambafiles' ssh via smbuser.

Comment: @ChristopherEvans Thanks... i checked the permissions which looked like  drwxrwxrwx 4 smbuser users 4096 Jul 5 08:41 /New_drive/ drwxrwxrwx 3 smbuser users 4096 Dec 30 05:02 /New_drive/sambafiles/ and the result of sestatus SELinux status: enabled SELinuxfs mount: /selinux Current mode: enforcing Mode from config file: enforcing Policy version: 21 Policy from config file: targeted

Comment: @JamesO'Gorman thank you very much for the suggestion. I tried to run the command but the effort is in vain. When running semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t "/New_drive(/.*)?" the following error comes "apacheds homedir /var/lib/apacheds or its parent directory conflicts with a
defined context in /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts,
/usr/sbin/genhomedircon will not create a new context. This usually indicates an incorrectly defined system account.  If it is a system account please make sure its login shell is /sbin/nologin.
"

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like SELinux is blocking this.

The [Fedora wiki entry](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/samba) has an entry on how to fix this. Essentially an [extended attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes#Linux) is needed for SELinux to allow non-default Samba shares.

```
chcon -t samba_share_t /New_drive
semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t "/New_drive(/.*)?"
restorecon -R -v /New_drive
```